# In Peoplesoft, How grid levels work in application designer?

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

Now I'm just having some training on PeopleSoft while working on application designer I could not understand grids and scroll levels, how it works on data fetch and result populating dynamically from multiple tables connected through parent-child relationship? Also stuck in people code `Getlevel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying it a bit too much, scroll levels correspond to parent-multichild relationships. If it's a single-value lookup, it's the same level - if it's an invoice header and invoice items, for example, they're different.